# Error getting when creating gin index on jsonb column postgresql9.5

Tags: postgresql, indexing, postgresql-9.5

I have `product_reviews` TABLE with `product_review` jsonb column.

```
jsonb column : [{"comment": [{"condition": "Good", "Entered": "true"}], "productid": 321}]

CREATE INDEX idx_product_reviews_product_review ON product_reviews  USING gin (CAST (product_review ->> 'productid') AS bigint )   ;
```

So when i try to create gin index on this jsonb column, i get error.

```
ERROR:  data type bigint has no default operator class for access method "gin"
HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
```

I want to index productid as bigint type values, so i can get jsonb "comment" values comparing this productid.

Comment: for functional index you shoul to use classic btree index - don't use gin

Comment: when i just change GIN with BTREE than no error given...

Comment: but why am i not allowed to use GIN like in my example?

Comment: Usually GIN,GiST indexes are used for types where operation `<` or `>` is not defined. When these operations are defined, then you can use a BTREE index. For almost all types the GIN, GIST index is supported or BTREE index is supported - not both cases.

Comment: Lets say, i have an array with unique integer elements. If i search for a particular value in an array then can/should i use GIN index for this array to get better performance?

Comment: and has the length of array anything to do with choosing index type?

Comment: a arrays can have GIN or GiST indexes. These indexes has different behave in dependency to result length and array length. You should to check corner cases.

Answer (score 0):

btree_gin https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/btree-gin.html extension provides gin operator classes for many data types, including bigint.

create the index after enabling btree_gin extension using

```
CREATE EXTENSION btree_gin;
```